# how to search input keyword from user database resume in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one text box name is Skills , if admin enter skill name we will get user data based on the user skills in database field . it will working fine . i can display all users data based on the skill set .

My requirement is if admin search any skill that skill is mentioned user in Resume also .i need based on the resume also display data in codeigniter. can you any one please help out this problem. Please find below QUERY in model.

```
SELECT  js_simple.js_id,js_simple.firstname,js_skills_achievements.skill,js_ResumeDetails.fileResume,js_ResumeDetails.profileImage FROM js_simple LEFT JOIN js_skills_achievements ON js_skills_achievements.js_id = js_simple.js_id WHERE js_skills_achievements.skill = '".trim($skill)."'
```

This is working for me , my requirement is user having resume . with in the resume suppose user mention skills is PHP,JAVA,SQL. if admin search any skill RESUME also i need search . What is QUERY for this in codeigniter model .

### view.php

```
<form id="advance_search" action="" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-8" style="border: 2px solid lightgray;padding: 0px 0px 9px 0px;">
                    <div class="advanced_serach_bg" style="background: #4a90cc;">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h4 style="color:#fff;"> Quick Search </h4>
                        </div>

                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label style="color:#323232;" for="pincode">Any keyword</label>
                               <input style="color:#535353; background:#f1f1f1;height: 35px;" id="keywords" class="form-control" name="keywords"  type="text">
                         </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label style="color:#323232;" for="pincode">Location</label>
                               <input style="color:#535353; background:#f1f1f1;" id="location" class="form-control" name="location" placeholder="Enter Location" type="text">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label style="color:#323232;" for="activein">Active in:</label>
                               <select style="background: #4a90cc;color:#fff;margin-top:2px;" name="active_records" id="active_records" class="form-control" >
                                     <option value='3 day'> 3 days</option>
                                    <option value='1 week'> 1 week</option>
                                    <option value='30 day'> 30 days</option>
                                    <option value='2 MONTH'> 2 months</option>
                                    <option value='3 MONTH'> 3 months</option>
                                    <option value='4 MONTH'> 4 months</option>
                                    <option value='5 MONTH'> 5 months</option>     
                                    <option value='6 MONTH'> 6 months</option>
                                    <option value='7 MONTH'> 7 months</option>
                                    <option value='8 MONTH'> 8 months</option>
                                    <option value='9 MONTH'>9 months</option>
                                    <option value='10 MONTH'> 10 months</option>
                                    <option value='11 MONTH'> 11 months</option>
                                    <option value='12 MONTH'> 12 months</option>
                                    <option value='10 Year'> 1 + Year</option>
                               </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>


                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div  class="col-md-offset-5 col-sm-4">
                            <input type="submit"  value="Search" class="btn btn-normal subbtn"> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                 </div>
             </form>
```

### javascript

```
<script>    
$(function(){
    $('form#advance_search').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();    
        var formData =  $('form#advance_search').serializeArray();
        //var keywords = $('#keywords').tagEditor('getTags')[0].tags;
        //console.log(keywords);
         $.ajax({   
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>newrecruiter_control/candidate_advance_search",
            type:"post",  
            data:formData,
            success:function(data) {  
                    window.location.href="<?php echo base_url();?>newrecruiter_control/search_candidate";
            }
         });   
    });
});</script>
```

### newrecruiter_control.php

```
public function candidate_advance_search() {     

         $this->recruiter_model->delete_candidate_search();
        $data['job_seeker'] = $this->recruiter_model->advance_candidate_search();

    }
```

### recruiter_model.php

```
<?php 
public function advance_candidate_search() {       

        $data = array(
                    'active_records' => $this->input->post('active_records')?$this->input->post('active_records'):'3 day',
                    'search_keyword' => $this->input->post('keywords')?$this->input->post('keywords'):'',
                    'semantic_search' =>  $this->input->post('search_mode')?$this->input->post('search_mode'):'ON',
                    'search_in_resume' => 'NO' //$this->input->post('search_resume')
        );        
        $sql_query = $this->db->select('*')
                                 ->from('recruiter_recent_search_results')
                                 ->where('recruiter_id',$this->session->userdata('recruiter_id'))
                                 ->get();
        if($sql_query->num_rows() >= 5 ){ 
            $this->db->delete('recruiter_recent_search_results',array('recruiter_id' => $this->session->userdata('recruiter_id')));
        }else{    
            $exp = $data['min_experience'];             
            $this->db->insert('recruiter_recent_search_results',array('recruiter_id' => $this->session->userdata('recruiter_id'),'skills' => strtoupper($data['search_keyword']), 'location' => ucfirst($data['location']),'experience' => $exp));
        }    


        if($data['search_in_resume'] == 'YES') {       
            /*

if($data['semantic_search'] == 'OFF') {  
                    $response_array  = $this->getAdvanceSearchResultInResume($data);
                }else{   
                    $response_array = $this->getAllSearchResultInResume($data);
                }*/
            }else{
                if($data['semantic_search'] == 'OFF') {  
                    $response_array  = $this->getAdvanceSearchResult($data);
                }else{   
                    $response_array = $this->getAllSearchResult($data);
                }      
            }    


        }  


        public function getAllSearchResult($data) {
            $search_query = "SELECT  js_simple.js_id,js_simple.firstname,js_simple.lastname,js_simple.added_date,js_skills_achievements.skill1,js_ResumeDetails.percentage,js_ResumeDetails.fileResume,js_ResumeDetails.profileImage,js_ResumeDetails.profile_type,js_ResumeDetails.about_self FROM js_simple LEFT JOIN js_skills_achievements ON js_skills_achievements.js_id = js_simple.js_id LEFT JOIN js_ResumeDetails ON js_ResumeDetails.js_id = js_simple.js_id WHERE js_simple.added_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL ".$data['active_records']." ) ";  

                if($data['search_keyword'] != NULL) {
                $search_key  = explode(',',$data['search_keyword']);
                if(count($search_key) == 1) {
                    $search_query .= " AND (js_skills_achievements.skill1 = '".trim($search_key[0])."' OR js_ResumeDetails.about_self LIKE '%".trim($search_key[0])."%')"; 
                    $str = $this->db->last_query($search_query);
                    echo $str;

                }
            } 

            $search_query .= " GROUP BY js_simple.js_id ORDER BY js_simple.added_date DESC LIMIT ".$data['sort_by'];


            $response = $this->db->query($search_query); 
             // return $this->db->last_query();
             return $response->result_array();  
        }   


        public function getAdvanceSearchResult($data) {    
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('js_simple,js_skills_achievements,js_ResumeDetails');
            $this->db->join('js_skills_achievements','js_skills_achievements.js_id = js_simple.js_id','left');
            $this->db->join('js_ResumeDetails','js_ResumeDetails.js_id = js_simple.js_id','left');
            $this->db->where("js_simple.added_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL ".$data['active_records']." )",NULL,FALSE); 

            if($data['search_keyword'] != NULL) {
                $search_key  = explode(',',$data['search_keyword']);
                if(count($search_key) == 1) {
                    $this->db->where('js_skills_achievements.skill1',$search_key[0]);                               
                }       
            }


            $this->db->group_by('js_simple.js_id');  
            $this->db->order_by('js_simple.added_date','desc'); 
            if($data['sort_by'] != NULL) {
                $this->db->limit($data['sort_by']);    
            } 
            $search_response = $this->db->get();
            return $search_response->result_array();                    

        }
    public function getAllSearchResultInResume($data) {  
        $jobseekers = ''; 
        $get_js_details = $this->getAllSearchResult($data);
        foreach($get_js_details as $key => $jobseeker) {
            if($jobseekers == NULL) {
                $jobseekers .= $jobseeker['js_id'];
            }else{
                $jobseekers .= ','.$jobseeker['js_id'];
            }
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Hi Anand , can i send model code or View,Controller and Model ?

Comment: yes upload it with all

Comment: Please check @AnandPandey

Comment: You want only mysql query on advance_candidate_search() function in model? You write here if($data['search_in_resume'] == 'YES') where you comment the code so is it any condition here for search in resume or not?

Comment: Yes i need search in resume also , I have resume Search function code , please check i will add in this post end of model .

Comment: I think the problem is occur when you explode bcoz you are check the first array value and data is 2 or more value containing. Is it given some error in query?